# Child class expected class-name before ‘{’ token C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, header-files

I know there are lot of similar questions, but I do not see my mistake here. 
I'm trying to inherit this class :

```
#if !defined(__GRAPHE_H__)
#define __GRAPHE_H__

#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class S>
class Graphe{
  public:
```

here :

```
#if !defined(__CARTE_H__)
#define __CARTE_H__

#include <cassert>
#include <istream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include "graphe.h"
#include "pointst.h"

using namespace std;

class Carte: public Graphe
{
```

but I have this error:  expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 {
I am not even using any functions from the parent class, so that's why I am not posting the whole code.

What I am missing?

Comment: `Graphe` is a template class.  When you specify it as a base for `Carte`, you are not providing a template parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should fix the problem;

```
using namespace std;
template <class S>
class Carte: public Graphe<S>
{
```

Comment: I got : error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
 <template class S>